# Induced Subgraph with the Largest Number of Edges

Tags: graph-theory, network, graph-connectivity, extremal-graph-theory

Is there an efficient way to find the induced subgraph with the largest number of edges among all the induced subgraphs of the same size?
For example, I have a 200-node graph H and I would like to find a 100-node induced subgraph that has the most edges.

Answer (score 2):

No (as long as $P \neq NP$).  Suppose such an algorithm existed.  Now, given a graph $G$ and an input $k$, we apply the putative procedure to find the densest $k$-vertex subgraph.  This subgraph will be a $k$-clique if and only if $G$ contains a $k$-clique.  Determining whether a graph has a $k$-clique is a standard NP-complete problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem .  Therefore your question is NP-hard.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your answer correctly, but I didn't expect the subplot to be a clique, as long as it is the densest among all the possible subplots.

Comment: @Wendy: It doesn't matter if you expect it, the point is that if you could do what you want efficiently, then you could also solve the clique decision problem efficiently.  (Technically, this is called a [polynomial-time] reduction.)  But the clique decision problem is NP-complete.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm quite new to graph theory : )

Comment: @Wendy: You're welcome.  The logic of polynomial reductions (really part of theoretical computer science, but with lots of applications in graph theory) takes a lot of getting used to.